# What is the correct way to call FILETOCLOB function in an insert statement for an SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql

I am converting my app from a informix DB to a SQL DB

I  get the following error on one of the quires ...
ex  {"'FILETOCLOB' is not a recognized built-in function name."}    System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

I am trying to execute the query below

INSERT INTO edi_user_pref (my_userid, user_pref_txt) 
VALUES(lower(@userID), FileToClob(@myXmlPath, \"server\"));

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using SQLServer, MySQL, SQLite, or what?

Comment: You are using SQL Client which is for a Microsoft SQL Server database.  The function FILETOCLOB is for an IBM database.  The two are not compatible.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1526.htm

Comment: @jdweng thanks. I had visited that page many times but seem to have missed that fact but is there anything I can use on the SQL Client that is similar?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I am using SQL Server

Comment: I do not know any functions in SQL Sever that writes to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement for the Informix FILETOCLOB (or FILETOBLOB) function. The way that SQL Server usually interacts with the Windows file system is either through the [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) mechanism directly, or by using the [FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) functionality, which is built on FILESTREAM.

These mechanisms are somewhat different, in that they offload large-object storage and retrieval onto the file system, rather than enabling storage of file content within the server itself.

To do exactly what the FILETOCLOB function does, you will have to retrieve the file contents using the `System.IO` namespace methods, and then store the resulting bytes in the database yourself.